# Jeditable not working with Ajax imported data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make table data cells editable. I am using a jQuery plugin called [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) to try and achieve this. Currently, I am using Ajax to get the necessary table data. My problem is when I try to edit the data nothing happens. I have tried using a table without ajax and it seems to work fine. Can anyone help me sort out this problem?

**My Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Attendance Alpha</title>
            <?php require_once('header.php'); ?>
        </head>
                <script>
     $('.status').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', {
         indicator : 'Saving...',
         tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
     });
        </script>

    <body onload="getStudents()">

        <div id="studentData"><p class="loading">Loading student data...</p></div>

    </body>
        <script>
            // START OF AJAX FUNCTION
function getStudents() {
// AUTO SETTING STR TO 1 (THIS IS FOR THE GET IN GET.PHP PAGE)
 var str = "1";
// DEFINE XHTTP
  var xhttp;
// CHECKS IF DATA HAS BEEN LOADED. THEN REMOVED THE "LOADING DATA" ALERT
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("studentData").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
// STARTS NEW REQUEST (AJAX)
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
// ONCE AJAX DATA HAS LOADED DEFINES WHERE TO PUT THE DATA
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("studentData").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
// BELOW HITS PAGE
  xhttp.open("GET", "GET.php?main_page="+str, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
// SETS INTERVAL ON HOW OFTEN THE PAGE SHOULD FETCH NEW DATA
setInterval(getStudents, 50000);
        </script>
    </html>
```

**And on the GET page:**

```
<?php
// REQUIRE NESSARY FILES
require_once('connection.php');
// QUERY STUDENTS
$query_results = $db_server->query("SELECT * FROM studentdata WHERE current = 1 ORDER BY firstname");
?>
<?php
// CHECKS IF GET VAR FOR DATA
if($_GET["main_page"] === "1") {

// PRINTING START OF TABLE OUTSIDE OF WHILE
print "<table>";
print "<th>Name</th>";
print "<th>Pr.</th>";
print "<th>Status</th>";
print "<th>Return</th>";

// GOING THROUGH STUDENT NAMES
while($row = $query_results->fetch_array()) {

// CONVERTS FIRST & LAST NAME INTO A SINGLE VARIABLE
// I WILL MAKE A FUNCTION FOR THIS SOON
        $NN_first = $row["firstname"];
        $NN_last = substr($row["lastname"], 0, 1);
        $NN_full = $NN_first.' '.$NN_last;
// PRINTING TABLE ROW
            print '<tr>';
        // PRINTS FULL NAME VARIABLE
            print '<td class="p_button"><span>'.$NN_full.'</span></td>';
        // PRINTS P BUTTON
            print '<td><input type="submit" value="P"></td>';
        // PRINTS CURRENT STATUS
            print '<td class="status">Field Trip</td>';
        // PRINTS CURRENT STATUS RETURN TIME
            print '<td class="return">EST. 11:45 am</td>';
        // PRINTS END TABLE ROW
            print '</tr>';

// BELOW CLOSES WHILE LOOP
}
// CLOSING TABLE
print "</table>";
// BELOW CLOSES CHECKING FOR GETTING DATA
}
?>
```

**Here is what output.php returns:**

[image]

Comment: Can you add GET.php output to your question ?

Comment: @IvanBarayev I added a picture of the output to the post. This is all in a table format. Thanks!

Comment: In your HTML I couldn't see the jquery and jquery.jeditable.js ! <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: @IvanBarayev Those files are there, just included in a header.php

Comment: Add all details please,